# Pushing play 2.0.x app to Heroku issue

Tags: deployment, heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to push a locally working app to Heroku but i'm getting this error

```
     [info] Compiling 20 Scala sources and 12 Java sources to /tmp/build_mhfyee4j841a/target/scala-2.9.1/classes...
       [error] /tmp/build_mhfyee4j841a/target/scala-2.9.1/src_managed/main/views/html/showitem.template.scala:74: value showItem is not a member of controllers.ReverseApplication
       [error]              <a href=""""),_display_(Seq[Any](/*45.21*/routes/*45.27*/.Application.showItem(p.id, Items.slugify(p.title)))),format.raw/*45.78*/("""" ><img width="110" height="110"  alt=""""),_display_(Seq[Any](/*45.118*/p/*45.119*/.title)),format.raw/*45.125*/("""" src=""""),_display_(Seq[Any](/*45.133*/p/*45.134*/.picture)),format.raw/*45.142*/(""""></a>
       [error]                                                                                    ^
       [error] one error found
       [error] {file:/tmp/build_mhfyee4j841a/}quoiacheter/compile:compile: Compilation failed
       [error] Total time: 25 s, completed Dec 8, 2012 8:07:38 PM
 !     Failed to build app with sbt
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Play 2.0 - java app
```

as i said before the app is running fine locally and you can see here the part that's supposed to have an error in ***showitem*** template

```
<p>
     @for(p <- Items.getRelated(item.categories.get(0).id) ) {
                <a href="@routes.Items.showItem(p.id, Items.slugify(p.title))" ><img width="110" height="110"  alt="@p.title" src="@p.picture"></a>
     } 
</p>
```

Heroku think that i'm calling `@routes.Application.showItem` instead of `@routes.Items.showItem` ! you can see here the concerned part of my routes file:

```
...
# ITEMS          
GET     /items/:id/:title           controllers.Items.showItem(id: Long,title: String)
...
```

Comment: What happens when you run `play clean` and then `play stage` locally?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason this should happen is if your `git` repository is not up to date and somehow in the git repo is calling `Application`, not `Items`. Please check you really committed your changes to `git` locally.